# Animate divs and order them by number with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-animate

here is the scenario that I should create:

there is OL list of numbers, (1,2,3,4,5,6). User can select/click those numbers. When one clicks it, the number should go to another OL list (animated, the number flys overe the screen). The numbers should be always in ordered order in the new list. So if user clicks first 5 it copies and flies to new list, and if user then clicks number 1, it should fly and go before 5. And so... so the new list numbers should something like 1,3,5 no matter in which order user clicked the numbers.

Ok, so that is what I want to achieve. Basically I can do the first part (user clicks the numbers -> it flies to new list), but then how to get the numbers in order always?

JS so far:

```
$('ol#original li').click(function() {
        $(this).clone().appendTo('ol#newNumbers');

        $('ol#original:last').animate({
            left: "150px",
            position: "relative",
            top: "150px",
        }, 600);
    });
```

OK, there is still problem that I append the cloned number to same ol list :/

Hopefully you understood and can help me bit. Thank you!

Comment: You are appending to the original ul, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

quick and simple solution is to create a bunch of empty `<li>` in the other `<ol>` and then use `$.replaceWith()`.  Another solution is to give each `<li>` a data attribute that maintain's the sort order.

(first option should be fine for most situations)

**edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/wA4ex/

```
/*create empty li's in newlist*/
for (var i=0; i < $('#oglist li').length; i++) {
    $('<li></li>').hide().appendTo($('#newlist'));
}

$('#oglist li').click(function(e) {
    var li = $(this),
        index = li.index(),
        clone = li.clone();
    $('#newlist li').eq(index).replaceWith(clone);
});
```

The main concept is to use place holders to maintain the order.

Comment: Didn't really get this. How this would help me to get numbers in right order?

Comment: @user1069269: check the fiddle

Comment: Thanks, this could do the trick. But now I'm not sure how to do the animation part (number flies from A -> N).

Comment: @user1069269 You were saying *"**Basically I can do the first part (user clicks the numbers -> it flies to new list),** but then how to get the numbers in order always?"* ;)